# Application_Reminder argument passed as string in Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I was following this blog post http://www.slipstick.com/developer/send-email-outlook-reminders-fires/ for reacting to Outlook 2010 Reminder event.   However, I kept getting tripped up because the argument passed to my event handler is a string that seems to be the "Subject" property of the reminder item.   In my "ThisOutlookSession" I have the simple code below:

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    post_frm Item
End Sub
```

Everything piece of documentation tells me that the Item should be an AppointmentItem, MailItem, ContactItem, or TaskItem, but I'm definitely getting a String, instead.

Any idea why?

Comment: In the link you posted, `Item` class was identified first before any processing is done. I think you should do the same before passing it to `post_frm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Subject property is the default property for Outlook items."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865652%28v=office.15%29.aspx

The code in post_frm is processing the default property of the item rather than the item.